# Why can't I invoke Array.prototype.map with Set object

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, ecmascript-6

I want to get get unique characters from some string using ES6's Set.
So let's assume that we have string `var str = 'abcdeaabc';` and create set of characters from this string:

```
var str = 'abcdeaadbc';
var chars = new Set(str);
```

Now we have the set of unique characters: `abcd`.
I was surprised that `char` set has `forEach` method and has no `map` method.

Set is iterable object, so why can't we use `map` function to iterate over set?

I tried to pass `chars` set and `chars.values()` SetIterator to `Array.prototype.map` this way:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(chars, function(element) {...});
Array.prototype.map.call(chars.values(), function(element) {...});
```

But every try failed.

For example, let's assume that we want to get unique symbols from string and return an array of them with preceding underscore. eg.: `['_a', '_b', '_c', '_d']`

Here are my two solutions:

```
// First:
var result = Array.from(chars).map(function(c) {
    return '_' + c;
});

// Second:
var result = [];
chars.forEach(function(c) {
    this.push('_' + c);
}, result);
```

But is there a way of invoking Array.prototype's `map` function with `Set` context? And if no - why?

Comment: Did you try using `Set.entries`? Actually, on second thought, I don't think that will work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35374005/5812121. Also as an alternative: `let result = [...chars].map(c => \`_${c}\`);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` works on array-like types that have integer indexes and a `length` property. `Set` and `Map` are general iterable types, but they are not array-like, so `Array.prototype` methods will not work on them. e.g.

```
var s = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
s.length === undefined;
s[0] === undefined
```

The main approach is `Array.from` kind of like your solution, but one thing to note is that `Array.from` takes a `mapFn` as the second argument, so you can do

```
let results = Array.from(chars, c => `_${c}`);
```

for a nice and short map to convert an iterable to an array.

Comment: set entries aren't accessible through index , but order is guaranteed ... I can't get over this :)

Comment: MDN sais that `Set` is iterable. And `Array.prototype.map`s specification sais that map gets iterable object: [MDN: map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). So why can't I pass set as an argument to `map`?

Comment: @YuriyYakym I think it's because a Set instance cannot be indexed with numeric indices like an array can, and that's what the array functions like `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.forEach()`, etc rely on.

Comment: Look at the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) on that same page, which is a step-by-step implementation of the spec, and you'll see it requires a `length` property, and that the values be addressable by index.

Comment: @YuriyYakym That link is for `Map`, not `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh, excuse me, I haven't noticed. Now it's getting clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Because even if `map` is generic enough to work for arbitrary array-like objects, not all iterable objects are array-like.

`map` just gets the `length` property, and then iterates properties from `0` to `length-1`. That can't work with sets because they have a `size` instead of `length`, and they don't provide random access to its elements.

If you really want to use `map`, you will need to transform the set to an array, and then transform the result back to a set.

```
var newSet = new Set(Array.from(set).map(myFunc));
```

But there is no point in doing that, it would be better to use set operations only:

```
var newSet = new Set();
for(let val of set) newSet.add(myFunc(val));
```

Or maybe a self-invoked generator function:

```
var newSet = new Set(function*() {
  for(let val of set) yield myFunc(val);
}());
```

Comment: Mapping over the result of `Array.from` will create a temporary array for no reason. You cal pass the callback as the second param.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate you can do like this

```js
var str = 'abcdeaadbc';
var chars = new Set(str);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify([...chars].map(c => c+"up")) + "</pre>")
```

Comment: Spreading and then mapping will create a temporary array for no reason. You can use `Array.from` to make an array and map at the same time.

Comment: @loganfsmyth :  The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object. (this is the first line of `Array.from()` description at MDN) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from This is very practical if you would like to use an array method aftervards like functional programming or pass the unique elements to a function as an argument array. There is no need to create a wasteful array for that.

Comment: My point is `[...chars].map(fn)` and `Array.from(chars).map(fn)` both create an array, then call `.map` to return a second array, whereas you can do `Array.from(chars, fn)` to create avoid creating the first temporary array.