# Array.from() vs spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

Is there some difference between using `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'))` or `[...document.querySelectorAll('div')]`?

Here is a example:

```
let spreadDivArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];
console.log(spreadDivArray);

let divArrayFrom = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
console.log(divArrayFrom);
```

The `console.log()` will log the same result.

Is there any performance difference?

Comment: good thing with spread operator is that it supports `Object`.

performance.. idk

Comment: To find out if there's any performance difference, run a benchmark. The results are likely to be quite different depending on whether you're in a native ES6 environment or transpiling to ES5.

Comment: The main difference is that `Array.from` works with array-like objects which don't implement the iterator protocol (i.e. `Symbol.iterator`). Even with ES6 and new browser specs, there are fewer and fewer of those.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196)

Comment: In addition to performance, there may be different upper limits in array size that these can handle. On Chrome at least, the spread operator seems to throw a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when used with very large arrays, while `Array.from()` works fine.

Answer (score 96):

Spread element or syntax (note that it's [not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37151966/3853934)) works only with objects that are [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) (i.e. implement the `@@iterator` method). [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) works also on array-like objects which are *not* iterable (i.e. objects that have indexed elements and a `length` property).

See this example:

```js
const arrayLikeObject = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', length: 2 };

// This logs ['a', 'b']
console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject));

// This throws TypeError: arrayLikeObject[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
console.log([...arrayLikeObject]);
```

Also, if you just want to convert something to an array, I think it's better to use `Array.from()` because it's more readable. Spread elements are useful for example when you want to concatenate multiple arrays (`['a', 'b', ...someArray, ...someOtherArray]`).

Comment: While I agree that `Array.from()` is an extremely readable way to implement this, I feel that the spread element syntax `...arrayLikeObject` is just as readable for people (or more so).

Comment: Also note spread syntax (`...arrayLikeObject`) is much shorter. That can be a factor sometimes, though maybe it shouldn't be.

Comment: @qarthandso If we are spreading into the new (different) array, then I would agree. But if we need to duplicate an array (into exact same one), then Array.from looks more attractive and at least in some cases more readable, i.e when we need to pass a starting value of `Array.prototype.reduce` to be the array, on which we called it.

Comment: Warning: number arguments such as `var i = 5; Array.from(i)` results in `[]` where as `var i = 5; [i]` results in `[5]`

Comment: @Eduard "Array.from looks more attractive" what makes programming syntax attractive?

Answer (score 12):

Well, `Array.from` is a static method, i.e., a function whereas the `spread` syntax is part of the array literal syntax. You can pass functions around like data, you can invoke them once, several times or not at all. This isn't possible with the `spread` syntax, which is static in this regard.

Another difference, which @nils has already pointed out, is that `Array.from` also works with array-like objects, which don't implement the iterable protocol. `spread` on the other hand requires iterables.

Comment: "Array.from also works with array-like objects, which don't implement the iterable protocol" -- can you give an example of one such object?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that spread `...` allows an array to be **expanded**, whereas `Array.from()` creates a **new array** directly.

In your example, `[...x]` creates a new array by using spread syntax to *expand* the existing array **values** into the array literal syntax– the brackets `[]` are what's actually doing the array-creation bit. Those brackets can be swapped out with any number of other syntax to achieve other results (e.g. spreading into function parameters `foo(...x)`, into an object `{...x}`, using multiple spreads to concatenate arrays `[...x, ...y]`, etc.).

`.from()` never expands upon anything, it always creates a new array based on the data provided.

Comment: Well, array literals always create a *new* array as well…

Comment: I'm not sure whether I just misunderstand your wording, but are you suggesting that the spread operator mutates the array instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @Bergi well the spread operator doesn't *create* an array. The array creation in OP's example is done via the square brackets surrounding the spread operator.

Comment: Ah, OK, I just wanted to be sure you meant the right thing. Maybe it would help if you said "expands the array literal" instead of "expands an array", since it doesn't operate on arbitrary arrays.

Comment: **To clarify:** The `...foo` syntax just spreads (expands) all array values as if they were separate, comma-separated arguments. The `[]` around it is what CREATES a new array. So `[...foo]` will create a new array and populate it by spreading all array elements as if they were array constructor arguments and does a FULL COPY of every element. Whereas `Array.from(foo)` will CREATE a new array using the input variable, and is A LOT FASTER because it creates a SHALLOW COPY (this is FASTER).

Comment: @MitchMcMabers they are both a shallow copy. It is _not_ true to say that spread does a "full copy."

Comment: This answer doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 3):

If the input is iterable they do the exact same thing.

However, based on the benchmarks, the spread operator seems to perform better for a Set.

https://jsben.ch/5lKjg

```js
let set = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  set.add(Math.random());
}


let tArrayFrom = window.performance.now()

let arr = Array.from(set)

console.log("Array.from():", window.performance.now() - tArrayFrom + "ms")


// slightly faster in most of the runs:
let tSpread = window.performance.now()

let arr2 = [...set];

console.log("Spread syntax:", window.performance.now() - tSpread + "ms")
```

Comment: On Chrome as of today, Array.from() seems slightly faster than spread now with this benchmark.

Comment: For me the spread syntax is faster by a couple ms

Answer (score 2):

Using Babel is a good way to see what's happening internally.

Heads up, though.  Make sure latest is selected in Babel, as the default is wrong.

Using your example above, this is the output.

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } else { return Array.from(arr); } }

var spreadDivArray = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(document.querySelectorAll('div')));
console.log(spreadDivArray);

var divArrayFrom = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
console.log(divArrayFrom);
```

Comment: `[].concat` doesn't appear to work if the node list is not concatspreadable? Is that a Babel output?

Comment: `Is that a Babel output` Indeed, I just copied the code to babeljs.io,  have you an example?, maybe babel does other transformations when required.   This of course is only doing testing for this specific case.

Comment: The babeljs.io repl has some weird options, it's not really reliable. Using `[].concat` is an incorrect simplification (does only do the same as spread syntax on array arguments), which might be caused by a bug in Babel or some unknown setting.

Comment: Oh, right.. I'll have to keep an eye on that one.  At first I thought I would delete this post, but thinking on might be worth keeping open as I wasn't aware babel was buggy.  What do you think?

Comment: Ah, clicking `latest` in babel makes a difference.. I'll update answer.. with new output.. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Not to mention that you *do not* see "what happens internally" when you look at Babel transpiled code. What a runtime does internally is something else entirely.

Comment: @Mörre  This post is well over 2 years old now.  From what I remember I think Chrome even used babel for a while, until it implemented naive code.  But that's not what I really was getting at when I said internally.  It might not work for everyone, but when i was learning ESNext features I found babel rather useful.

Answer (score -3):

I need to clarify everyone's answers:

- The `...foo` syntax just spreads (expands) all array values as if they were separate, comma-separated arguments. It does a shallow spread. Any primities (numbers, strings etc) are COPIED and any complex values (objects) are instead REFERENCED.
- The `[]` around it is what CREATES a new array.
- So `[...foo]` will create a new array and populate it by doing a SHALLOW COPY spreading of all array elements as if they were array constructor arguments which in turn takes all those copied elements and puts them in the new array.
- Whereas `Array.from(foo)` will CREATE a new array using the input variable, but is A LOT FASTER because it ONLY creates a SHALLOW COPY (this is FASTER). So it takes the exact input and just puts every variable/reference into the new array.
- Use `Array.from()`.

Comment: This is incorrect both the spread operator and `array.from()` creates shallow copies.