# Remove duplicates form an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var array = [
    {id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
    {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
    {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
    {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
    ...
];
```

As you can see, some names are repeated. I want to get a new array with names only, but if some name repeats I don't want to add it again. I want this array:

```
var newArray = ["Name1", "Name2"];
```

I'm trying to do this with `map`:

```
var newArray = array.map((a) => {
    return a.name;
});
```

But the problem is that this returns:

```
newArray = ["Name1", "Name1", "Name2", "Name2"];
```

How can I set some condition inside `map`, so it won't return an element that already exists? I want to do this with `map` or some other ECMAScript 5 or ECMAScript 6 feature.

Comment: Then remove the duplicates from the array.

Comment: How about a `Set`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645/1048572)

Comment: Why does the line containing id:125 not end with a comma?

Comment: Please note that all the answers using .indexOf() will have **poor performance** if the array is large, due to their quadratic [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). I would recommend using [ES6 Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364654/99777) or using an [ES5 object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024565/99777) as a dictionary.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values, after mapping only the names of the objects.

This proposal uses a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for collecting the items in a new array.

```js
const array = [{ id: 123, value: "value1", name:"Name1" }, { id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1" }, { id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2" }, { id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2" }],
      names = [...new Set(array.map(a => a.name))];

console.log(names);
```

Comment: For my info.. what does `...` do?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, it's a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for building an array with an iterable object.

Comment: I'm not upvoting for the "Set" itself, but rather for the clever use of the spread operator. It's always nice to learn something new or to see something new applied to a practical example, so this post deserves an upvote.

Comment: Why throw away the `Set` after you’ve made it? I would argue that `names` should be left as a `Set`—after all, it *is* a set. And `console.log`, at the very least, has no problem with printing it *as* a set. Some libraries may require an array (having not been updated to ES6, or allowing duplicates), but leaving it as a `Set` until it is necessary to use an array saves developer headspace: the runtime itself is keeping track of the fact that `names` is supposed to have unique values, so the developer doesn’t have to remember that. Also, “cleverness” deserves a well-named utility function.

Comment: @KRyan, right, it is better to keep a data structure until the data is finally used, but the question requires an array as result and that's why the spread syntax.

Comment: @NinaScholz Answers are allowed to, and should when appropriate, point out better practices than those requested. I’m not saying you should *remove* the method of achieving an array from the `Set`, just that you should also mention that there may be better approaches. And I do think suggesting a `toArrayFromSet` utility function for the `set => [...set]` would be a good idea, since that syntax is going to be unclear to other developers (at least for now, with ES6 being so new).

Comment: @KRyan I agree that abusing spread syntax is a bad practise here, but there's no point in constructing an `toArrayFromSet` function - it already exists as [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @Bergi Ah, perfect: I had checked `Set` for that, forgot to check `Array`.

Comment: @Bergi, please add some sources about the bad practice of using spread syntax with sets.

Comment: It's just my personal opinion, but a [rather common one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40549565/1048572). Using `Array.from` conveys the intent of conversion much better (and also is easier to understand/search for newbies), spread syntax should be used only where the spreaded element is one of many. Maybe calling it a "bad practise" is a bit too harsh, sorry, I just hope to prevent it from becoming a common idiom.

Comment: @KRyan is ES6 so new? It has been finalized in 2015 june. It's time to start understanding and using the new features

Comment: @edc65 “Start” is the key phrase there. Browser support for it is still incomplete (and older browser's often still need support), which means many, many developers are paying zero attention to it. I would agree that is a mistake, but it’s also a fact.

Answer (score 66):

If you are looking for a JavaScript solution that is not ES 6 (no Set) you can use the [Array's `reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var array=[
  {id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
  {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
  {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
  {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
];
var names = array.reduce(function (a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(b.name) == -1) {
    a.push(b.name)
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: This answer also has the benefit that it doesn't require intermediate arrays or sets, especially ones containing only the names themselves. (It goes directly from array of objects to array of objects.) +1

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce, isn't this second param the same object as the returned one?

Comment: Yea but it doesnt go straight from one to the other like sort or filter, its rebuilt from an empty array.

Comment: filter doesn't act on the original array either, it does create a new array. reduce doesn't : it outputs what you passed in.

Comment: and i guess internally sort and filter build the array one item at time too all i'm saying is it starts with an "intermediate" array and build it into the desired array, effectively the same way you would do with a loop, whereas sort and filter just take a function and return a new array.

Comment: @Dekel — Smaller version :) `var names = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a.indexOf(b.name) === -1 && a.push(b.name)
  return a;
}, []);`

Comment: @Rayon Please don't pay too much attention to the size of the source code, this is a common pitfall for many self made programmers, most importantly, your program should be efficient and readable.

Answer (score 18):

Personally I don't see why everyone is getting all fancy with ES 6. If it were my code I'd prefer to support as many browsers as possible.

```js
var array=[
{id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
{id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
{id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
{id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
];

   // Create array of unique names
var a = (function(a){
  for (var i = array.length; i--;)
    if (a.indexOf(array[i].name) < 0) a.push(array[i].name);
  return a;
})([]);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Won't it be more performant to use an object as a dictionary instead of `indexOf`-ing all the time? E.g. do `added[name] = true` and `if(added[name])` instead of `if(a.indexOf(name))`.

Comment: @BojidarMarinov depends on the number of items, really

Comment: "personally i don't see why everyone is getting all fancy with es6"  why are you courting a `goto fail`, leaking your index variable into the enclosing scope, etc. etc. ES6 was codified into the standard for good reasons, and is for the most part trivially easy to polyfill/transform for older browsers.

Comment: If leaking this and that is really an issue its even easier to put it ina closure but at that point you might as well use a polyfill.. its 2016 most people writing javascript are probably not writing enterprise level software

Comment: "i don't see why everyone is getting all fancy with es6": because there are transpilers that convert the code to the old syntax. more readable for the programmer, but equally supported!

Comment: More readable? Its a its a freaking for loop that pushes items onto an array. Doesnt get much more readable than that......

Comment: Ive added a comment for anyone who has trouble understanding loops and arrays.. and i addressed the comment above like 12 hours before you even up voted it..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I think the readability in syntactic terms is more or less a wash, and the "functional" version is not any shorter in this instance. The reason people don't use `for` loops anymore and prefer Sets to Arrays has more to do with *correctness*. No fencepost errors, runtime guarantees dedupe, etc. etc. That's not even including the potential `goto fail` still present in your version at the time I write this.

Comment: There is no goto in javascript so i honestly dont know what youre talking about. Feel free to enlighten me but frankly it will be hard to take it at face value from someone who says "people dont use for loops anymore." You seem to be missing the point of backwards compatibilty which is the whole reason i posted this.

Comment: Quite honestly it just feels like youre trying way too hard to find something to complain about.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. You invited people to complain about *your* code by virtue of your (unnecessary) comment about the other answers. Backwards compatibility is a total red herring, other commenters and myself have pointed out that *multiple* code transformers exist. And of course there's no `goto` in JavaScript, I am referring to the famous Apple SSL bug that was introduced by using a conditional without the braces (followed by someone else adding another line to the clause). https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/

Comment: "I am referring to the famous Apple SSL bug" -- It's not that famous that you can just go and refer to it in random comments out of context and expect people to recognize it.

Answer (score 17):

You could also simply combine `map` with `filter`

```js
var array = [
  {id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
  {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
  {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
  {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
];

var unique = array
  .map( item => item.name )
  .filter( ( item, idx, arr ) => arr.indexOf( item ) == idx ) 

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of a given object's own enumerable property names from the object result of iterating `array` variable with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) where the keys are the [destructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) names

Code:

```js
const array = [{id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"}, {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"}, {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"}, {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}],
      names = Object.keys(
        array.reduce((a, { name }) => (a[name] = 1, a), {})
      )

console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 9):

Many good answers here. I just would like to contribute with some diversity with hopes to give you another perspective.

Arrays are of object type in JavaScript, so they can be used as a hash at the same time. By using this functionality we can greatly simplify the job to be done in a single reduce operation with O(n) time complexity.

If you are not happy with your array holding some properties other than the array keys you might consider keeping a separate hash object as well.

```js
var array = [{id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
             {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
             {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
             {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
            ],
result = array.reduce((p,c) => p[c.name] ? p : (p[c.name] = true, p.push(c.name), p), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This ES5 solution has good performance, but using the array for two purposes is confusing, and dangerous if one of the names is just a number. I would recommend doing the `p[c.name]` stuff on a separate object `o` and then discarding it afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

I agree that if you only need the `name` values, a `Set` is the way to go.

*However*, if you want to get an array of unique objects based on the `name` property, I'd suggest to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/map). A quick way to create a Map, is via an array of `[key, value]` arrays:

```js
const array = [{ id: 123, value: "value1", name:"Name1" }, { id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1" }, { id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2" }, { id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2" }],
      unique = new Map(array.map(obj => [obj.name, obj]));

// To get the unique objects
const uniques = Array.from(unique.values());

// Get the names like you already did:
console.log("Names:", uniques.map(obj => obj.name));

// If you ever need the complete array of unique objects, you got a ref:
console.log(JSON.stringify(uniques));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

An added benefit of `Map` is that you get both the `filter` functionality that cuts out the non-uniques, without loosing the connection with the source objects. Of course, it's only needed if you need to reference the unique set of objects multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 this should do the job.

```js
var array=[
    {id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
    {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
    {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
    {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}
];

var set = new Set();

array.forEach((a)=>{
    set.add(a.name);
}); 

console.log(Array.from(set));
```

Comment: `map` is supposed to be used with pure functions, not to have side effects. This would be a job for `forEach` or `reduce`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're limited to ES5, I would use [Lodash's `_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq)

```
var newArray = _.uniq(array.map(function(a) {
  return a.name;
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using UnderscoreJS,

```js
array = [{id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"}, {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"}, {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"}, {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}];
get_names =  _.pluck(_.uniq(array, 'name'), 'name')
console.log(get_names)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

That's how I did it, using a separate empty array.

```js
var array = [
   {id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},
   {id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},
   {id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},
   {id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}     
];

var array2 = []  
  
for (i=0; i<array.length;i++){      
   if (array2.indexOf(array[i].name) == -1){    
     array2.push(array[i].name);
    }
}   

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nArr = [];
array.forEach((a) => {
    if (nArr.indexOf(a.name) < 0) { 
        nArr.push(a.name); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES5, use an object as a dictionary for O(*n*) performance.

This will only work if all the keys are Strings.

```
var array = [
    {id: 123, value: "value1", name: "Name1"},
    {id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1"},
    {id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2"},
    {id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2"}
];

var allNames = array.map(item => item.name);

var map = {};
allNames.forEach(name => {
  map[name] = true;
});
var uniqueNames = Object.keys(map);

console.log(uniqueNames);
```

You could do the same thing in one expression if you like:

```
var uniqueNames = Object.keys(allNames.reduce((m, n) => (m[n] = true, m), {}));
```

but I find the imperative form easier to read.

Comment: I used ES6 arrow functions for clarity. If you really are targeting ES5 without a transpiler, then you will need to use the full form instead: `function (item) { return item.name; }`

Comment: As an alternative to `Object.keys()`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/99777) uses `filter()` to keep only those names which have not yet been stored in the map, which is quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`array#forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [**`array#indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods like this if you want **maximum compatibility** yet, concise syntax:

```js
const array = [{ id: 123, value: "value1", name:"Name1" }, { id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1" }, { id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2" }, { id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2" }]

// initialize an empty array named names
let names = [];

// iterate through every element of `array` & check if it's 'name' key's value already in names array if not ADD it 
array.forEach(function(element) { if (names.indexOf(element.name) === -1) names.push(element.name) });
// or use tilde like this:
//array.forEach(function(element) { if (~names.indexOf(element.name)) names.push(element.name) });

console.log(names);
```

However, if compatibility is **not an issue** use *ECMAScript 6*'s [**`Set`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object, [**`array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [**`Array.from()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) methods like this:

```js
const array = [{ id: 123, value: "value1", name:"Name1" }, { id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1" }, { id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2" }, { id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2" }];

// iterate through every element from array using map and store it in Set(a Set won't have duplicates) then convert the Set back to Array(using Array.from)
let names = Array.from(new Set(array.map(element => element.name)));

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a lot of spread-Set-like solutions, that aren't optimal.

This solution is simpler, more efficient and doesn't needs to recreate array:

```js
const array = [{ id: 123, value: "value1", name:"Name1" }, { id: 124, value: "value2", name: "Name1" }, { id: 125, value: "value3", name: "Name2" }, { id: 126, value: "value4", name: "Name2" }]

const res = array.map(e => e.name)
                 .filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) == i)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

For those seeking a 1 liner

```
const names = array.reduce((acc, {name}) => acc.includes(name) ? acc : [name, ...acc], []);
```

or without using methods on the array's prototype

```
const { reduce, includes } = Array;
const names = reduce(array, (acc, {name}) => includes(acc, name) ? acc : [name, ...acc], []);
```

could be usefull for writing some pure functions for dealing with this

```
const get_uniq_values = (key, arr) => reduce(arr, (a, o) => includes(a, o[key]) ? a : [o[key], ...a], []);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var __array=[{id:123, value:"value1", name:"Name1"},{id:124, value:"value2", name:"Name1"},{id:125, value:"value3", name:"Name2"},{id:126, value:"value4", name:"Name2"}];

function __checkArray(__obj){
    var flag = true;
    for(let i=0; i < __array.length; i++){
        if(__obj.id == __array.id){
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

var __valToPush = {id: 127, value: "value5", name: "Name3"};
if(__checkArray(__valToPush)){
    __array.push(__valToPush)
}
```

Comment: do you have a special reason to use so much underscores?