# Why isn't MS Edge working with spread element and querySelector?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

In another question posted this was there:

```js
var a = {};
a.products = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')];
console.log(a.products);
```

```html
<div class="product"> </div>
```

Edge will fail with the following error:

> function expected

However this is working:

```js
    var params = ['hello', '', 7];
    var other = [ 1, 2, ...params];

console.log(params);
console.log(other);
```

Why isn't the top one working on Edge (it does on Chrome)?

Comment: Have you tried `[...(document.querySelectorAll('.product'))]`?

Comment: I did on your suggestion, not working!

Comment: Edge might not implement the iterator protocol for `NodeList`s? *edit:* yep: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility (at least it doesn't support `entries()`, `values()`, etc, which I believe it would if it supported the iterator protocol).

Comment: The error message isn't all too helpful, but it *probably* means "expected `document.querySelectorAll('.product')[Symbol.iterator]` to be a function".

Comment: It looks like node lists were made iterable in the Windows 10 Fall Creators update: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/15898300-iterable-nodelists

Comment: @JDB: you are right. I've updated the question with snippets and they will now function in line with other browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which generates an array from an array like object.

```
this.products = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.product'));
```

Comment: It's the [preferred syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40549565/1048572) for type conversions anyway

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like Bergi and Felix are on the right track: in this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) on MDN they talk about iterators.

> Some built-in constructs, such as the spread operator, use the same iteration protocol under the hood:

So where Array does have `entries()` a `nodelist` in Edge doesn't and does not support iteration.

Nina's answer is the goto one!

Answer (score 0):

Update to 2020, Edge is now using Chrome v8 internally.
Ask the user to download latest version of Edge. No need to take care of this specific scenario in old Edge.