# Can't send a Set() object via socket.io in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, set

I'm trying to send a `Set()` object via `socket.io` from `node.js` server. But from client side I'm getting an empty object.

```
//server side
var set=new Set([1,2,3]);
socket.emit('set', set);
console.log(set); //Set(3) {1,2,3}
```

```
//client side
socket.on('set',function(set){
  console.log(set); //{}
});
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack):

> All serializable datastructures are supported, including `Buffer`.

`Set` is not serializable (try doing `JSON.stringify(new Set([1, 2, 3]))`. However, `Array` is serializable and you can convert a set into an array with a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const s = new Set([1,2,3]);
socket.emit('set', [...s]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Are there any performance difference between [...s] & Array.from(s)

Comment: @Chamod It all depends on your environment - are you running natively or are you transpiling into ES5? Also, in most scenarios differences are going to be negligible. Have a look at [Array.from() vs spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548213/array-from-vs-spread-syntax)