# Select all inputs.value

Tags: javascript

I have 4 inputs in my form and select them with querySelectorAll. I want to check if the value of all inputs is not empty, how can I do it in an efficient way?

what I did:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input'):
if (inputs[0,1,2,3].value !== '') {
        alert('submit');
        form.reset();
    }
```

Comment: More efficient is to add the attribute `required` to the input tag. Then the form cannot be submitted unless the field has value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the list of nodes into an array, and then use `.every()`:

```
const allFilled = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".input"))
  .every(input => input.value !== "");
```

Your attempt: `inputs[0,1,2,3].value` will not work; JavaScript does not provide the implied facility. Instead, `inputs[0,1,2,3]` ends up being exactly the same as `inputs[3]`, because the commas are parsed as the "comma operator", which is an expression separator. The first three expressions are evaluated but the values are ignored; the overall result is simply `3`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. that was so informative for me.

Answer (score 2):

`inputs[0,1,2,3]` is not the way how you access each element in the array. You need to go every index to obtain the value from the array.

**Solution:**

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

// converting NodeList to array as .some works with the `Array`
const inputsArray = [...inputs];

const anyEmptyInput = inputsArray.some(input => input.value === '');

if(!anyEmptyInput){
  alert('submit');
  form.reset();
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='input' />
<input type='text' class='input' />
<input type='text' class='input' />
<input type='text' class='input' />
```

You can try giving the `values` to these `inputs` in your code and check the result.

Comment: I like the positive some rather than the negative every. However I am also warming to Array.from when creating an Array from something. [here is a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548213/array-from-vs-spread-syntax)

Comment: @mplungjan Totally agree!! However, I still feel we should consider performance before readability. `.some` is an optimised solution as compared to `.every`.

Comment: Why YOUR however? I just said, I prefer your some and === to the every and !== :) You can still use Array.from instead of [...] and have the same readability, maybe even more since you truly want to create an array

Comment: "HOWEVER" comes from the other discussion, not from your statement :) I checked in that thread and it's debatable on the "readability" aspect (more in the comments there). It's a perception (as in how you see it) but point taken, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less the canonical version of a form with validation. When the input element has the `required` attribute all the inputs need to validate before the form can be submitted. In the example the `city` just has `required` and just need some value to validate, `name` must be at least 4 characters long, `address` cannot be longer than 20, and the value of `zip` must be between 2 and 4 digits (there is also an input with the type of `number`, that only validates if the value is a number...).

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('all inputs have a value...');
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="name" minLength="4" required />
  <input type="text" name="address" maxLength="20" required />
  <input type="text" name="zip" pattern="[0-9]{2,4}" required />
  <input type="text" name="city" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```